# Mass push notifications in WP7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

In my project, I need to send a lot of equal push notifications to a lot of windows phone devices. Is there a way to send a push notification with multiple receivers or do I have to make one http request per device? I've found a lot of good tutorials but no information about this issue.

Good tutorial (has downloadable project with server, wpf application and wp7 app which works immediately): http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/02/a-really-long-post-about-the-windows-phone-7-push.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make one http request per device. Because when you are sending the request you are sending it to url that's generated by Microsoft for registered device and each of those URL's are unique.

For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can use Windows Azure Notification Hubs service to send push notification to many devices in a group identified by a tag. 
For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx#BKMK_NH6